# Laravel 5.1 extra field for authentication

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm making my first big project using `Laravel 5.1` and I'd like to add an extra check during user login to see if the user has activated their account.

This is the schema of the `users` table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(true);
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I've tried adding a `$credentials['is_active'] = true;` after `$credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);` in `AutheticatesUser@postLogin` and it works but I want to have a custom error if the user's account isn't active because the default one(`These credentials do not match our records.`) is not that intuitive for the user.

Any suggestions in achieving that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the postLogin method in your AuthController and check whether the user is active or not like this.

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
public function postLogin(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
          'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);
   $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);
  // This section is the only change
  if (Auth::validate($credentials)) {
      $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();
      if ($user->is_active) {
          Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));
          return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
      } else {
         return redirect($this->loginPath()) // Change this to redirect elsewhee
        ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            'active' => 'Please active your account'
          ]);
      }
  }
   return redirect($this->loginPath())
      ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
      ->withErrors([
          'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
   ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can check following way

```
 if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password,'is_admin'=>1]))
       {
            return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
       }
```

Comment: Yes.. I made the check but my problem was I wanted to specify a custom error if the user's account is inactive

Comment: you can use else statement for that